# node-remote require local node module

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

my main option is a remote page, so I need to work with node-remote. But I have some question about it.

1. how to set multiple address?
2. how to require local node modules?

Comment: Did you google it?

Comment: yes~~is that any question？